# Getting SQL to link Data

Tags: sql

How to I link "profileID" to the profile name in a different table? and return the name rather then the "profileID"?

So far I have:

```
SELECT profileID
FROM TABLE1
```

This is going on a grid.
Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the tables using profileId

Example1:

```
select
  desired_column_name
from
  table1, table2
where
  table1.profileID = table2.profileID and
  table1.profileID = desired_profileId_value
```

Example2:

```
select
  desired_column_name
from
  table1
    join table2 
      on table2.profileID = table1.profileID
where
  table1.profileID = desired_profile_id_value
```

Comment: THANKS! Although I had trouble making it work so I took off the "AND table1.profileID = desired_profileId_value" in example 1 and it worked fine.